# How do I know if my LinkedList is already ordered?

Tags: java

```
private static LinkedList<Integer> melhorMoto1 = new LinkedList<>();
```

I know I can do something like create a new LinkedList, use `newLinkedList = melhorMoto1;`and do `Collections.sort(newLinkedList);` and `newLinkedList.equals(melhorMoto1 );` but as I'm working with recursive function, the  `newLinkedList = melhorMoto1;` is a very slow attribution. Can I check if the LinkedList is ordered with a method or something?

Comment: Checking if it's ordered is as simple as iterating it and verifying that the order is maintained between any two adjacent items.

Comment: "create a new LinkedList, use newLinkedList = melhorMoto1;" that code doesn't create new LinkedList, it assigns to `newLinkedList` reference to LinkedList which is held in melhorMoto1 variable. What you probably think of is something like `LinkedList<Integer> newLinkedList = new LinkedList<>(melhorMoto1)`

Comment: Nop. When i say 'newLinkedList = melhorMoto1;' I'm whereas that I already created the newLinkedList (with 'LinkedList<Integer> newLinkedList = new LinkedList<>()' ofc);

Comment: Then what's the assignment for?

Comment: I think i wasnt clear. I want to know if there is one LinkedList method that I cant use to check if the list is ordered or no. For exemple: melhorMoto1.isOrdered that return 1 if yes or 0 if not.

Comment: Even if you created `LinkedList<Integer> newLinkedList = new LinkedList<>()` if you later do `newLinkedList = melhorMoto1;` you are discarding that new LinkedList you just created and *assign* to `newLinkedList` reference to list held by `melhorMoto1`. If that is not the case then clarify your question so people wouldn't waste their time on clarifying it.

Comment: It is to assign melhorMoto1 values to newLikedList, but i just realized that I can use `newLikedList=  new LinkedList<Integer>(melhorMoto1);`. w/e

Comment: As i said, i CAN do it. Whatever, @BeeOnRope already helped me. Sorry for the not clear question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java 8, you can use `Comparators.isInOrder(Iterable)` to achieve this for a `List` (or any other ordered collection).

Prior to Java 7, do it yourself: to check that any `List` is sorted in ascending order, simply iterate through it and check that the current element `cur` is greater or equal to the previous element `prev` for each adjacent pair of elements.

Change that to less than or equal for descending order. This requires `size() - 1` total checks.

Comment: Thank you. I was just looking for a method that do it for me automatically.

Comment: There is no built-in method, but writing it is only a few lines of code. Put it in a utility class and you'll have it forever. If you really want a "built in" probably the closest you can is using streams to create a temporary sorted list to compare to, like `list.equals(list.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList()))`, but this is going to be quite inefficient compared to an iterative method. @marcos

Comment: @Marcos - apparently I was wrong, Java 8 has `Comparators.isInOrder(Iterable)` which does what you want.